# Where does UDDI used to get queried by client about wsdl in the CODE

Tags: java, web-services, uddi

I am new to web services and I am learning that a requestor will query the UDDI for wsdl location. My question is: where can the UDDI be used to get wsdl document located upon the requestor query **in our CODE** not theoretically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how jaxws works.  Try using apache juddi client lib, that works around this issue by including the wsdl in the jar and specifying a class path location of the wsdl